# CSS line break after n list item `inline-block`

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I have a problem to add a line break after a N (3 for example) elements of a list: I have tried to do like this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609279/css-to-line-break-before-after-a-particular-inline-block-item) solution (using `:nth-child(3):after { content:"\A"; white-space:pre; }`) tells but id didn't work for me.

Here is my css

```
.lk-color-chooser {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.lk-color-chooser__color {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.5;
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.lk-color-chooser__color:hover,
.lk-color-chooser__color.selected {
 opacity: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 }
.lk-color-chooser__color:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IW7RWWkZKHnNDuAZLbx5?p=preview)
The code is done in angular but the problem is a css one.

Here is one of the list element :
`<li class="lk-color-chooser__color ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" style="background-color: #72C2FF" ng-repeat="color in colors track by $index" color="color" ng-class="{'selected': selectedColor == color}">&nbsp;</li>`

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There's no list element in your plunker, how did you try the solution you mentioned?

Comment: the list is generated via angular directive `<li class="lk-color-chooser__color" style="background-color: {{ color }}">&nbsp;</li>` you can see it using an html inspector.

Comment: I added an example to the question

Comment: I don't see any angular or `li` elements in the plunkr either

Comment: I'm sorry it's my fault it was the wrong plunker. It's fine now

Comment: Check out the 2nd answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768902/how-to-insert-new-line-within-ng-repeat-of-the-middle-angularjs-twitter-boots), suggests using `<br ng-if="($index+1)%3==0">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from css's nth child selector and the display: inline-block/block combination.

You may want a CSS fix for this, and I'm sure it exists, but this also works. It's up to you if you're that concerned about the inline conditional.

I made this span a few lines so people wouldn't have to scroll to see the code that fixes it.

This was fixed via one change in your template:

```
template: '<ul class="lk-color-chooser">
              <lk-color  ng-repeat-start="color in colors track by $index" color="color" ng-class="{\'selected\': selectedColor == color}">
              </lk-color>{{$index}}
              <br ng-if="($index + 1) % 3 == 0" ng-repeat-end>
           </ul>',
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li:nth-child(3){
color: red;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

pseudo properties like ':after' won't work

http://codepen.io/chiranjeeb/pen/waBObM